# Information not being put into database

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

Here's what I have at the top of the page, gathering the information from the tables in the database:

```
include_once '../assets/database.php';
$a = $_GET['a']; 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$user_q->execute();
$user_i = $user_q->fetch();

$aboutQ = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE uid = :id");
$aboutQ->execute(array(':id' => $user_i['id']));
$about = $aboutQ->fetch();

$about_ex = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE uid = :uid");
$about_ex->execute(array(':uid' => $user_i['id']));
$aboutRow = $about_ex->rowCount();
```

and the bottom queries, creating a new row or updating an existing one, depending on if the user has a row in the table already:

```
if($a === "post") {
$motto = $_POST['motto'];
$bio = stripslashes($_POST['bio']);
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$aboutUid = $_POST['uid'];
if($aboutRow == 0) {
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `info` (motto, bio, grade, sex, favevent, position, phone, hours, uid) VALUES (:motto, :bio, :grade, :sex, null, null, :phone, null, :uid)");
$q->bindParam(':motto', $motto);
$q->bindParam(':bio', $bio);
$q->bindParam(':grade', $grade);
$q->bindParam(':sex', $sex);
$q->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$q->bindParam(':uid', $aboutUid);
$q->execute();
}
else {
$q = $db->prepare("UPDATE `info` SET motto=?, bio=?, grade=?, sex=?, favevent=?, position=?, phone=? hours=? WHERE uid=?");
$q->execute(array($motto,$bio,$grade,$sex,null,null,$phone,null,$aboutUid));
}
header("Location: ../members");
exit;
}
```

It's not giving me an error - but every time I execute it nothing happens.

Comment: Why should it give you an error? Check with [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/mysqli-error) & [`mysqli_errno()`](http://php.net/mysqli-errno) after query execution.

Comment: Where's your error/value checking on those initial SELECT's values?

Comment: @CORRUPT - that looks more like PDO to me; in which case, it's `$db->ErrorInfo()` and `$q->ErrorInfo()`

Comment: @andrewsi It's not giving me anything.

Comment: Have you confirmed the value of the session user id and your other variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've got SQL syntax errors:

```
$q = $db->prepare("UPDATE ... position=?, phone=? hours=? WHERE uid=?");
                                                 ^-- missing comma
```

since you say no errors are showing, you're probably not running with exceptions enabled, so you absolutely **MUST** check return values from DB calls and check for boolean false.